# What timestamp format is this value 1522899000000? ionic or AngularJS. How can I use it in Java

Tags: javascript, java, json, timestamp

I'm reading JSON from a third party URL. In that JSON data I found this timestamp starttime: 1522899000000 (on 4/5/2018 -> 5th April 2018)...I thought that it is Unix timestamp and tried to convert but it said Year 1912 :-). What timestamp is this? I'm reading this JSON from my Java app. How do I convert it to Java datetime?

Comment: Divide it by 1000... (it's in ms) to get a Unix timestamp, that gives `2018-04-05 03:30:00 UTC` :-) Number of seconds since 1970. Or use it as it is in Java[script].

Comment: `date --date='@1522899000'`

Comment: I think it's Unix but in milliseconds so divide it by 1k and try it ?

Comment: Tried to convert how? Please edit the question to include some code

Comment: Worked...thx. I tried to convert it using PHP since it is quick echo $time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s A T", $jsontimestamp); I should have checked directly in Java :-)

Comment: While dividing by 1000 will work, no need to do the math explicitly at such a low level. You’ll get more readable code from leaving the math to standard library classes. Ring Ø and @d-coder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

Apparently, `1522899000000` is a count of milliseconds since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of [1970-01-01T00:00:00Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_522_899_000_000L )
```

> 2018-04-05T03:30:00Z

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`).

Your input seems to be a count of milliseconds since the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00Z. Sometimes known as [*Unix time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), though not definitively.

### `Instant`

So parse as an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
long input = 1_522_899_000_000L ;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( input );
```

> instant.toString(): 2018-04-05T03:30:00Z

If your input is textual, parse as a number with [`Long.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String)).

```
long input = Long.parseLong( "1522899000000" ) ;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( input );
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

An `Instant` is always in UTC, by definition. If you want to see that same moment through the wall-clock time used by people of a certain region (a time zone), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-04-05T15:30+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]

### `DateTimeFormatter`

The strings generated above are in standard ISO 8601 format. For other formats, search Stack Overflow for the `DateTimeFormatter` class.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

try this timestamp in 10 digit

```
 import java.text.DateFormat;
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.Date;
 public class HelloWorld{

//1522899000
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Date d = new Date((long)1522899000*1000);
    DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.mmm'Z'");
    System.out.println(f.format(d));
 }
}
```

**OP**

```
2018-04-05T03:30:00.030Z
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: `….030Z`? Why the fraction of a second?

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: This code does NOT work properly because receivers of output string will interprete it in UTC but it was generated for the system timezone of the current JVM, very bad.

Comment: Expected output: `2018-04-05T03:30:00Z`. Observed output on my computer: `2018-04-05T05:30:00.030Z`. The hours are 5 instead of 3, and 30 milliseconds have been added, apparently out of nowhere. Of course these bugs can be fixed, but it will be much simpler to switch to the `java.time` solution shown in the other answer.

Comment: 1- you used `.mmm` for the fraction of seconds, but `m` is for the **minutes**. For fraction of seconds, you must use `.SSS`. 2- `'Z'` (inside quotes) prints a literal Z (the letter Z itself), but the Z in the end means the date/time is in UTC and it shouldn't be added like this - more than that, the formatter will use JVM default timezone, but it'll print the Z, giving an incorrect UTC value depending on JVM config (as noted by Meno's comment above). You should use `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");` and then set it to UTC with  `f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`